# Is it in the site's habits and customs to keep an upvoted question with answer, despite the quality of the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The following question is currently in the hotlist: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196661/is-there-any-complete-logical-connective.

I think this is a bad question. Firstly, the title does not match at all the content of the question. Secondly, the OP does not show any attempt to work out the solution. Finally, questions about complete sets of connective were asked on the main site before and were answered. While this question is not an exact duplicate of the previously asked questions, it is in the same spirit and reading the previous questions would give the OP the proof techniques he needs to answer his own question.

Despite this, the questions received upvotes and has an answer. I don't really understand why this question is judged good by the community, while some questions of similar quality are immediately closed as missing context. Shouldn't this question be closed? Or is it too late, just because it already has an answer?

Comment: The question is closed (now). The answerer may also not be aware of the things mentioned here, since they are also very new. I am more flexible about new users answering such things than about higher-rep users who should know better.

Comment: Unfortunately, the community is split on this issue. Some users believe that anything resembling mathematically correct content must be preserved for eternity. Other users maintain that some quality control must be exercised. Even users in the latter group are not always in agreement about the standards that must be maintained. As for my personal opinion, I believe unsuitable questions (including the one you linked) should be closed, even if they got an answer and/or upvotes, even if they are old, and eventually deleted if they are not improved in the meantime.

Comment: I see, thank you for the comments. @Carl, is there an incentive for a user who received an answer to improve his question?

Comment: @zarathustra: not really. That's why it's important for established users to be patient before writing answers to such questions. In this case, the person asking also seems to be less fluent in English, which may be another factor.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this other meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19917/why-isnt-more-being-done-to-avoid-facilitating-copy-paste-homework-questions).

Comment: Not sure how much I should say here, but a look through the user's profile should convince you that much of the approval is coming not from a wider community. That these questions receive answers might still need addressing.

Comment: The OP appears to have very minimal fluency in English and may well be unable to provide much more than a bare question. The previous related answers, like the textbook, may or may not be sufficient for any given student, regardless of what you or I think ought to be the case. In any case the answer is a good one and deserves its upvotes. You should be aware that the comments are not representative: Carl and Najib are at one extreme of the spectrum of views on this topic, and I am at the other.

Comment: I think understanding (in a broader context) comes with age.

Comment: Note that the question has now been deleted.